# How to get values from component in displaywith property of mat-slider

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using `Angular Material v6`. 
[Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api) says that `displaywith` it's a "Function that will be used to format the value before it is displayed in the thumb label." And it ought to be used like that:

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel [displayWith]="formatRateLabel" [value] = 'movie.mark'>
</mat-slider>
```

In my component class I have a `formatRateLabel` function:

```
formatRateLabel(value: number) {
        if (!value) 
          return 0;
        return "HI!"; //just for demonstration
      }
```

What I need is to get values of my component from inside that function. I usually do such thing by using `this` keyword inside some function. But when I do it from that `fornatRateLabel` function properties of my component are undefined. As I understand it's kind of scope problem. Word `this` in this function has access to the all properties and functions of mat-slider only. But I need the access to my component's properties from that function. Let me show:
Here's my component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './movieLibrary.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./movieLibrary.component.css']
})
export class MovieLibraryComponent{
    someProperty : boolean = true;

    formatRateLabel(value: number){
    var myLocalVariable = this.someProperty;// debug showed it's as undefined. Why? 
   }
}
```

I've tried to pass some parameters to `formatRateLabel` 
like this

```
[displayWith]="formatRateLabel(movie.mark)"
```

but in that case thumb label becomes empty, so that's not working either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"this" in your `formatRateLabel` function is pointed to the slider not your component itself.

So, you need to tell it what "this" should be.
The simplest solution is to

1. change your `formatRateLabel` in your .ts file to be a functional such as

`formatRateLabel = (v: boolean) => {
    return (value: number) => {
      var myLocalVariable = v; 
      ... // Do something
   }
 }`

2. change your `formatRateLabel` in your .html file to be

`[displayWith]="formatRateLabel(someProperty)"`

so that this variable `someproperty` can be passed into your function.

Comment: If somebody can help understand why the scope behaves weirdly, would be of great help..

Answer (score 5):

You have few ways to fix this issue but the simplest and most appropriate solution to fix this issue is by using function expression. Simply redefine the `formatRateLabel` in the following way.

```
formatRateLabel = (value: number) => {
    var myLocalVariable = this.someProperty;
}
```

Hopefully this should work.

Answer (score 4):

As I found, the really easiest way is add this code to the `constructor` function of your component:

```
this.formatLabel = this.formatLabel.bind(this);
```

then your function will be applied with right `this` linked.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but i find this one a better solution. Just bind this to the html component, like this:

```
<mat-slider thumbLabel [displayWith]="formatRateLabel.bind(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I guess it's going to be useful for anyone who comes across that thread in the future and is wondering what requires binding the component context explicitly.

`displayWith` is declared as an @Input property, implementing an arrow function in the [Angular Material components library](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/slider/slider.ts#L357).

Moreover, you could also see that the `displayWith` input is invoked also internally into the [`_updateValueIndicator` method](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/slider/slider.ts#L757), which is a part of the function chain that gets invoked when the thumbs are being dragged. It's this invocation that falls back to the user-defined handler, which would also transfer the context of the invocator and waste your own this context within the function in your very own component.

Therefore, in case one is willing to use variables from the component, where the handler is implemented, they would need to bind the context of the component explicitly.

I opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26789) with a description of the issue, hoping that if not refactoring that snippet, they would atleast mention it into the docs, since I also found it a bit confusing at first.